# Django fast Many-To-Many filtering

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

Lets say that i have two models: Category and Product

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length='255')
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='children', related_query_name='child')

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length='255')
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

I have about 6mln products and 12k categories in my DB. Each product has mutiply categories. I want to filter products by category_id:

```
    categories = [1, 5, 6, 7, ....]
    products = Product.objects.filter(category__pk__in=categories)
```

Filtering on MtM field can return dublicates, so i need to distinct(). But with distict fitering can take up to 15 sec. Is there any way to get distict products faster? I would appreciate that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try approaching it from the other side. Get the ids of products from categories, and then filter products by ids. In my tests I'm getting a 60% improvement.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length='255')
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name="products")

product_ids = Category.objects.filter(id__in=categories).values_list("products__id", flat=True).distinct()
products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
```

Comment: Thanks! Now filtering takes up to 5 sec, thats just great